# What does SaturatedOpacity mean in Rawtherapee?

Tags: color, white-balance, saturation, rawtherapee

When checking differences between Rawtherapee `.pp3` profiles, I noticed a `SaturatedOpacity` parameter under `[ColorToning]`, either equal to 0 or 1, and likely set by the white balance point tool.

I may have missed it but launching Rawtherapee with two profiles having different `SaturatedOpacity` values I wasn't able to spot the parameter to which it corresponds.

What does `SaturatedOpacity` correspond to in Rawtherapee ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following snippet from a `pp3` file created by RawTherapee:

```
[ColorToning]
SatProtectionThreshold=25
SaturatedOpacity=75
```

The settings are associated with the **Saturation Protection** settings of the [**Color Toning**](https://rawpedia.rawtherapee.com/Color_Toning) filter. They are available for most, but not, all of the methods. I chose "RGB - Sliders" because it is compact and fits well on screen.

[image: Color Toning]

Comment: Wow, given all 35 files had either 0 or 1 values, I would never have expected a slider…

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more code review, the `SaturatedOpacity` value in the sidecar file seems to correspond to:

```
Color -> Color Toning -> Opacity
   -> Saturation Protection -> Strength slider/field entry
```

`SaturationThreshold` would be the other parameter in that group. The mix of camelCase, PascalCase and lowercase can get a bit confusing at times...

---

Based on this line in the source code:

```
saveToKeyfile(!pedited || pedited->colorToning.saturatedopacity,
   "ColorToning", "SaturatedOpacity", colorToning.saturatedOpacity, keyFile);
```

I'm gonna guess it's related to the Opacity subsection in the Color Toning section under the Color tab. The variable is a `bool`, and it's a member of a structure called ColorToningEdited, so it's probably just an indicator to look for and/or use/ignore some other variables that contain the customized curves, etc. that make up the rest of the settings in that part of the module.

Comment: twalbert - Edited to make your answer clearer/easier to understand... I'd written and posted my answer before realizing you'd already added it to yours.